# Saxon S9API Java, dealing with comments

Tags: java, xml, schematron

So I'm trying to use a schematron to validate an XML. from the `XdmNode` I'm getting the following warning

!--WARNING: Rule for context "test:responseTest" shadowed by
preceding rule-->

this is when looping through all the XdmNodes from the rootnode

```java
            for (XdmNode node : rootnode.children().iterator().next().children()) {
                 if(node.getNodeKind() == XdmNodeKind.COMMENT) {
                    continue;
                }
             }
```

is this an issue with the schematron or how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post minimal but complete sample to allow us to reproduce the problem. You mention Schematron but you don't explain which implementation you are using or are trying to use. Does running Schematron with an established tool like Schxslt or the Skeleton implementation give a similar warning comment, perhaps created in the XSLT the implementation creates from the Schematron schema?

Comment: Deleting the s9api tag (which I didn't know existed!) as this is a pure Schematron issue, nothing to do with Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

I see this warning in a Schxslt generated SVRL report if I duplicate a rule with the same `context` inside of a `pattern` e.g.

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="root">
            <assert test="@*">root has no attributes.</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context="root">
            <assert test="@*">root has no attributes.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

when applied on

```
<root>This is an example.</root>
```

generates a report like

```
<svrl:schematron-output xmlns:error="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#error" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:schxslt-api="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#api" xmlns:schxslt="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494" xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <svrl:metadata xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#">
      <dct:creator>
         <dct:Agent>
            <skos:prefLabel>SaxonJS/2.5</skos:prefLabel>
         </dct:Agent>
      </dct:creator>
      <dct:created>2023-06-22T16:19:23.998+02:00</dct:created>
      <dct:source>
         <rdf:Description xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
            <dct:creator>
               <dct:Agent>
                  <skos:prefLabel>SchXslt/1.9.3 SaxonJS/2.5</skos:prefLabel>
                  <schxslt.compile.typed-variables xmlns="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#">true</schxslt.compile.typed-variables>
               </dct:Agent>
            </dct:creator>
            <dct:created>2023-06-22T16:19:23.716+02:00</dct:created>
         </rdf:Description>
      </dct:source>
   </svrl:metadata>
   <svrl:active-pattern documents="https://martin-honnen.github.io/schematron-fiddle/schxslt/1.9.3/run-pipeline-for-svrl-and-apply-to-schema.sef.json"/>
   <svrl:fired-rule context="root"/>
   <svrl:failed-assert location="/Q{}root[1]" test="@*">
      <svrl:text>root has no attributes.</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>
   <!--WARNING: Rule for context "root" shadowed by preceding rule--><svrl:suppressed-rule context="root"/>
</svrl:schematron-output>
```

which is basically an attempt by Schxslt to point out that the second `assert` is not taken into account as only the first match is used; depending on your intentions and schema and instance documents this might happen but it could also be a coding error in the Schematron schema so I think the warning is helpful in that case.

Schxslt has a parameter `<xsl:param name="schxslt.svrl.compact" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>` that by default is false, if you set it to `true()` then I think warning and suppressed-rule output will not occur.

As for the question in a comment as to which line a suppressed-rule refers to, it appears that the Schematron SVRL or Schxslt implementation doesn't assume you want e.g. a `location` attribute on those elements but it is easy to change or override two templates in `svrl.xsl` of Schxslt to do e.g.

```
  <xsl:template name="schxslt-api:fired-rule">
    <xsl:param name="rule" as="element(sch:rule)" required="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="location-function" as="xs:string" required="yes" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$schxslt.svrl.compact eq false()">
      <svrl:fired-rule location="{{{$location-function}({('.')[1]})}}">
        <xsl:sequence select="($rule/@id, $rule/@role, $rule/@flag, $rule/@see, $rule/@icon, $rule/@fpi, $rule/@xml:*)"/>
        <attribute name="context">
          <xsl:value-of select="$rule/@context"/>
        </attribute>
      </svrl:fired-rule>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="schxslt-api:suppressed-rule">
    <xsl:param name="rule" as="element(sch:rule)" required="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="location-function" as="xs:string" required="yes" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$schxslt.svrl.compact eq false()">
      <xsl:variable name="message">
        WARNING: Rule <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@id)"/> for context "<xsl:value-of select="@context"/>" shadowed by preceding rule
      </xsl:variable>
      <comment> <xsl:sequence select="normalize-space($message)"/> </comment>
      <svrl:suppressed-rule location="{{{$location-function}({('.')[1]})}}">
        <xsl:sequence select="($rule/@id, $rule/@role, $rule/@flag, $rule/@see, $rule/@icon, $rule/@fpi)"/>
        <attribute name="context">
          <xsl:value-of select="$rule/@context"/>
        </attribute>
      </svrl:suppressed-rule>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

then you get output like e.g. `<svrl:fired-rule location="/Q{}root[1]" context="*"/>` and `<svrl:suppressed-rule location="/Q{}root[1]/Q{}item[1]" context="*"/>`.

Comment: great thank you. how can i find out which line in the file this refers too? if i do getLineNumber method call it only tells me "-1"

Comment: Do you have a file? And which file are you talking about, the Schematron schema with the suppressed rule, the XML instance with the matched node, the generated XSLT?

Comment: The generated XLST points out that that a rule is shadowed by preceding rule but how can i determine which rule in the .sch file i need to change? I tried searching for the context but the context only has 1 match in the .sch file.

Comment: @santi254, consider to raise that as a separate question where you show minimal but complete samples of the Schematron, the XML and the version of Schxslt you use, to allow others to easily reproduce the problem. Then we can hopefully figure out what goes wrong. But without minimal but complete details it won't work, I guessed what could be the reason and gave an example but it doesn't make sense that I have to guess and produce a Schematron sample, provide it yourself in the details of your question.